# Lazy-loading with Angular Ivy : No provider for InjectionToken ng-select-selection-model

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-ngselect, angular-ivy

**Bug Description**
I'm using angular's new IVY compiler, along with the new lazy-loading functionality (lazy-loading with ivy tutorial here: https://www.debugbear.com/blog/lazy-loading-angular-components-without-a-router)

When lazy-loading a module and adding an instance of a component to my app, the ng-select does not appear in the component and I get this error in the console:

`core.js:6354 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken ng-select-selection-model -> InjectionToken ng-select-selection-model -> InjectionToken ng-select-selection-model]:
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken ng-select-selection-model!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:8736:27)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:24378:33)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:24378:33)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:24378:33)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:40184:33)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:38095:35)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:12876:39)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:28245:12)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.NgSelectComponent_Factory [as factory] (http://localhost:4200/lazy-lazy-module.js:4143:398)
    at getNodeInjectable (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:13021:44)`

**Reproducible example**
see https://github.com/boltex/ivy-lazyload-test for a minimal repo exposing this bug.

**To Reproduce** 
1. clone the example repo `git clone https://github.com/boltex/ivy-lazyload-test`
2. run `npm install` to get all dependencies
3. run `ng serve`

**Expected behavior**
When trying this locally with ng serve, when the program loads in your browser, press the "Lazy load module & add instance of component below" button. (This will add some components instance into the app) The component should have an ng-select in it. It doesn't and forementionned error appears in the console.

**Note**
Ignore the first error in the console: **Uncaught TypeError: ng.probe is not a function**
It is a normal error to get when using angular 9 because augury assumes angular dev mode is active if window.ng exists, but ivy doesn't export probe right now.

**Here's a screenshot**
[image]

**My Current Setup**
 - OS: [windows 10]
 - Browser [chrome]
 - Version [78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)]

Thanks for your time and attention to this issue !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution with @HeroDev's 'hero-loader' component.
(See their relatively short source code for the additional techniques it uses: https://github.com/herodevs/herodevs-packages/tree/master/projects)

The method I was using was not fully compatible with all methods of integrating componnent, 3rd party or otherwise, into an existing application by lazy-loading. (Not using routing)

I've updated my repository https://github.com/boltex/ivy-lazyload-test with a working example where you can add, and remove, arbitrary number of different modules and components into an opened application without changing routes.